# select only one element from an priority ordered group with limits?

Tags: mysql, group-by

This question searches for an answer in pure sql (no db-server specific code)

-edit-
Due comments/answers:
"pure sql" - SQL92/99 because this works on all servers. I do not only use this code on mysql, this was just the first one I tried. I have to support Microsoft SQL Server (2000!), h2, PostGRE SQL and MySQL Server but the code should work on others too (db server independent). I'm sorry if "pure sql" was not detailed enough. Next time I'll specify requirement of the revision of SQL (3/4, 92/99)

I have to be backwards compatible.
And this is why I did not specify a db server. This was on purpose.
-end-of-edit-

I try to get all values from a table with given limits.
The data i have for the query is: possible locales and a max_priority

this is the table to work with

```
SELECT * FROM i18n
```

.

```
id|featureName|locale     |priority|text
--+-----------+-----------+--------+----
 1| type      |         en|       1|father
 2| type      |         de|       2|Vater
 3| type      |      de_AT|       3|Papa
 4| type      | de_AT_Wien|       4|Oida
 5| firstName |         en|       1|first name
 6| firstName |         de|       2|Vorname
 7| lastName  |         en|       1|last name
 8| lastName  |         de|       2|Nachname
 9| lastName  |         fr|       2|nom de famille
10| firstName |         fr|       2|prénom
```

so for example i have `en`, `de`, `de_AT` and a max_priority of 3 (which is the priority of `de_AT`)
i expect this as result: (the order of these results are not important!)

```
id|featureName|locale     |priority|text
--+-----------+-----------+--------+----
 3| type      |      de_AT|       3|Papa
 6| firstName |         de|       2|Vorname
 8| lastName  |         de|       2|Nachname
```

i tried to solve this with an `left outer join`
this is the best result i was able to get:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nls1.*
FROM i18n nls1
LEFT OUTER JOIN i18n nls2
ON (
    nls1.featureName = nls2.featureName
    and nls1.priority > nls2.priority
)
WHERE nls2.priority<=3
AND (nls1.locale='en' OR nls1.locale='de' OR nls1.locale='de_AT')
GROUP BY featureName
ORDER BY featureName, priority DESC
```

but this selects those rows:

```
id|featureName|locale     |priority|text
--+-----------+-----------+--------+----
 2| type      |         de|       2|Vater
 6| firstName |         de|       2|Vorname
 8| lastName  |         de|       2|Nachname
```

another try was

```
SELECT nls2.* 
FROM   i18n nls2 
       JOIN (SELECT Max(priority) max_priority, 
                    featurename, 
                    priority 
             FROM   i18n nls 
             WHERE  ( locale = 'en' 
                       OR locale = 'de' 
                       OR locale = 'de_AT' ) 
                    AND priority <= 3 
             GROUP  BY featurename) nls3 
         ON nls3.priority = nls2.priority 
            AND nls3.featurename = nls2.featurename
```

but this one only returns the en version...

```
id|featureName|locale     |priority|text
--+-----------+-----------+--------+----
 1| type      |         en|       1|father
 5| firstName |         en|       1|first name
 7| lastName  |         en|       1|last name
```

NOTE: i'll update the question depending on the answers.

The main problem seems that i need a `group by` an `column` but the group also needs a `order by`?

Comment: Regarding the edit: you do not want pure SQL. a_horse's answer is pure SQL, too. You want a very limited set of SQL, if you want something that runs as it is, in MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, h2 and who knows what else.) If you ever need date/datetime functions in a query, you'll probbaly hit a dead end. Nothing works at all of these. If you try a simple UPDATE taking data from 2 tables the same.

Comment: Plus, you are restricting youself to code that may not run efficiently in most of the DBMS. Why not use separate queries for each DBMS if needed?

Comment: Because I do generate sql scripts via program code for generic classes. You are right THIS example could be written in for different dbms. But doing so for a very limited count of queries does not make much sense (especially if they are only executed once in a while - startup of an application or when the user changes the language)

Comment: Beside that, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without window functions, the query will be complicated. One way to solve the problem in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    n.*
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT featureName
      FROM i18n
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    i18n AS n
  ON  n.id = 
      ( SELECT i.id
        FROM i18n AS i
        WHERE i.featureName = d.featureName
          AND i.locale IN ('en', 'de', 'de_AT')
          AND i.priority <= 3
        ORDER BY i.priority DESC
        LIMIT 1
      ) 
ORDER BY 
    n.featureName ;           -- or whatever you like, eg:  BY n.id
```

Also note that the above query will fail it is in SQL Server (which uses `TOP`, not `LIMIT`) and possibly fail in other DBMS as well.

Answer (score 1):

With [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) this can easily be solved using window functions:

```
select id, featurename, locale, priority, text
from (
  select i.*,
         row_number() over (partition by i.featurename order by i.priority desc) as rn
  from i18n i
  where i.locale in ('en', 'de', 'de_AT') --<< this is the list of locales you are looking for
    and i.priority <= 3 --<< this is the max priority
) t
where rn = 1
order by featurename, priority desc;
```

The above is standard SQL without any DBMS specific code

Comment: modern SQL does not seem to be supported by MySQL 5.6.28 - modern SQL is not pure enough :) Err#1305 FUNCTION row_number does not exist

Comment: @lumo: you asked for a DBMS independent solution, not one that works with the exteremly limited SQL features in MySQL. Window functions have been part of the SQL standard for over a decade.

Comment: @lumo you shoudl always tag questions with the DBMS you are working with. So you get better answers and not waste other people's time. Please edit your question and add the version of MySQL as well.